# Why doesn't the increment operator work with Element.id but does with Element.name in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am dynamically creating HTML elements, IDs and names for a HTML form using JavaScript. The ++ operator does not work when trying to assign the incremented value to an ID using Element.id. It does work when assigning an incremented value to a name using Element.name though. What is the reason for this difference?

```
locationQuantity = 0;
newInputField.id = "location" + locationQuantity++; 
newInputField.name = "location" + locationQuantity;
```

Take this bit of code as an example. When I inspect the dynamically created element in the browser, the element will have id="location0" and name="location1". The ++ operator clearly did work since name is incremented, but the id displays as if the ++ operator did not work. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/itzamna/3xkjsqdm/6/) is a working example of the behavior.

I understand how to work around this, I'm just curious as to why this happens.

Comment: The value gets returned before the `++` occurs. Try `"location" + (++locationQuantity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```js
locationQuantity = 0;
newInputField.id = "location" + locationQuantity++;
```

is equal to this:

```js
locationQuantity = 0;
newInputField.id = "location" + locationQuantity;
locationQuantity = locationQuantity + 1;
```

So:

```js
locationQuantity = 0;
newInputField.id = "location" + locationQuantity; //locationQuantity is 0
locationQuantity = locationQuantity + 1; //locationQuantity  is now 1
newInputField.name = "location" + locationQuantity; //"location" + 1
```